# Jasper Report integration to Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Tried the code below but the PDF reports is not generated. Just started with Jasper integartion. Please help.

```
public String mainReport() {
      HashMap jrxmlParams = null;


      try {
       System.out.println("Start ....");
       // Get jasper report
       String jrxmlFileName = "C:/Jasper/DP_crosstabs.jrxml";


       JasperReport objJReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxmlFileName);

       connection = getConnection();

       jrxmlParams = new HashMap();
       jrxmlParams.put("ID", "null");

       JasperPrint objJPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(objJReport, jrxmlParams, connection);

       ByteArrayOutputStream objBAOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

       JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(objJPrint, objBAOutputStream);



       System.out.println("Done exporting reports to pdf");



      } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.print("Exceptiion" + e);
      }
    return null;
     }
```

Comment: Have added all relative jar files, can someone assist

Comment: Is this a desktop application?

Answer (score 6):

Try the below code ,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     String reportPath = "/report3.jasper";
     Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     Connection connection;

    try {


          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/person","root","password");

        System.out.println("Filling report...");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, params, connection);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,
                            "/Test.pdf");
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Sadagopan, it worked :)... But as per project requirement we have to generate the report in HTML format. Able to create the file with Export Manager but unable to view the same at the same instance. Kindly help!!!

Comment: Hi Jasper viewer will trigger the generated report in the same instance for all formats..  Please mark the above as answer. Thanks